# The sum of several items in a json

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON source with more empty_slots elements (in the example exist below only one, but in the reality exist more stations with empty_slots). How can I sum the values from empty_slots and return as double? Thanks!

JAVA

```
  public static double getValueFromJSONString(String jString) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jString);


    return json.getJSONObject("empty_bikes").getDouble(jString);
}
```

JSON

```
{"network": {

"company": [
 "Gewista Werbegesellschaft m.b.H"
 ], 
"id": "citybike-wien", 
"location": {
"city": "Wien", 
}, 
"stations": [
 {
 "empty_slots": 3, 
 "extra": {
 "slots": "26", 
 }, 
 "free_bikes": 23
  }]}
```

Comment: parse the json, get the array of `stations` loop around this array getting the integer for `empty_slots` add them together as you loop. Done. https://github.com/square/moshi

Answer (score 0):

Checkout JsonPath. Below code is not tested but should work with RestAssured dependency - https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(jsonString);

List<Integer> companyEntityIds = jsonPath.getList("network.stations.empty_slots");
```

Once you have the array you can just use a stream or whatever to add these up.